# How can I change Ultimate Member Restriction set as “Everyone” as default, on install?

Tags: wordpress, ultimate-member

I added Ultimate Member plugin to my WordPress website.  I have 100 pages and 560 posts that were added prior to the plugin.

```
[Image mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F7Fy.png)
```

By default, after adding the plugin, all pages and post are not set for restricted access (Figure 1).

What I would like to do is have them all set to “Logged in users” (Figure 2)

Since I don’t have the time to set restrictions one by one, is there a way to do it globally (using code, probably) so all of them become restricted?

Other than checking the database to see if there’s a way to do it I haven’t tried anything else.  I don’t write code :(